# How python can read and modify the CSV

Tags: python, pandas

```
**iShares Russell 3000 ETF                                          
Inception Date  May 22, 2000                                        
Fund Holdings as of 31-oct-16                                       
Total Net Assets    $ 6,308,266,677                                     
Shares Outstanding  48,550,000                                      
Stock   -                                       
Bond    -                                       
Cash    -                                       
Other   -**                                     
Â                                           
Ticker  Name    Asset Class Weight (%)  Price   Shares  Market Value    Notional Value  Sector  SEDOL   ISIN    Exchange
AAPL    APPLE INC   Equity  2.8074  113.54  1,521,794   $ 172,784,491   172,784,490.76  Information Technology  2046251 US0378331005    NASDAQ
MSFT    MICROSOFT CORP  Equity  2.0474  59.92   2,103,008   $ 126,012,239   126,012,239.36  Information Technology  2588173 US5949181045    NASDAQ
XOM EXXON MOBIL CORP    Equity  1.5675  83.32   1,157,835   $ 96,470,812    96,470,812.20   Energy  2326618 US30231G1022    New York Stock Exchange Inc.
JNJ JOHNSON & JOHNSON   Equity  1.4378  115.99  762,927 $ 88,491,903    88,491,902.73   Health Care 2475833 US4781601046    New York Stock Exchange Inc.
```

I am trying to delete the basic info and read just the structured data below, Pandas read csv is throwing error.

Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: Show us your code for what you have tried to so far.  Then we can offer guidance/feedback.

Comment: You should also clarify what you mean by "basic info"

Comment: To avoid this in future, please read [ask] and [mcve] and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: To avoid this in future, please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to discard the non-csv header, and that your file is tab separated afterwards (it cannot be space or it isn't a parsable csv file due to the lack of quotes and presence of space in data)

In that case you could iterate until you find the title, and then create a csv `reader` on the file, like this:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv") as f:
    while(True):
        l=next(f)  # read input file lines
        if not l or l.startswith("Ticker"):  # title found (or end of file, safety)
            break

        cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
        for row in cr:
            print(row)   # get valid rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jean, I found a work around for the problem by using your code.